# Revit API ExternalResourceReference.CreateLocalResource returns null

Tags: revit-api

I have a Revit application that registers an external resource server and uses an external event to change the keynote table and I'm getting some odd behavior.  The general idea is that when I give it a path through the UI it will tell Revit to load the keynote table at that path, which can be a resource on my external resource server.  Here is the relevant portion of the code:

```
...preceeding code...

var knt = KeynoteTable.GetKeynoteTable(app.ActiveUIDocument.Document);

var mp = ModelPathUtils.ConvertUserVisiblePathToModelPath(_dbManager.ActiveDB.FilePath);
var extRef = ExternalResourceReference.CreateLocalResource(app.ActiveUIDocument.Document,
    ExternalResourceTypes.BuiltInExternalResourceTypes.KeynoteTable, mp, PathType.Absolute);

if (knt == null) throw new Exception("Keynote table was null on reload, could not change files");
if (mp == null) throw new Exception("Model path was null, could not change files");
if (extRef == null) throw new Exception("External Resource Reference was null, could not change files");

...following code...
```

So in short it gets the keynote table object, creates a model path from the file path given (held in `_dbManager.ActiveDB.FilePath`), then creates an external reference object from it.  It then later uses that to load the keynote table from:

```
using (var t = new Transaction(app.ActiveUIDocument.Document, "Change Keynote File"))
{
    t.Start();
    knt.LoadFrom(extRef, null);
    t.Commit();
}
```

This works just fine using the single folder paths that my server usually has, something like `RDCloud://Something/File.txt`.  However, when you get a deeper path like `RDCloud://Something/AnotherThing/File.txt` (which happens far less often in my app but does happen) the call to get the `extRef` object returns null so it ends up throwing an exception.

Any ideas as to why this is null here?  Is that expected?  Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I distrust backslash. Can you use forward slashes instead?

Comment: I actually went back and checked and it's actually a forward slash already so that's not it.  Updating question...

Comment: I [asked](https://app.slack.com/client/T02NW42JD/C02NW42JP) the devteam for you...

Comment: The devteam asks: Can the user recreate this problem in the UI?

Comment: How would you do it through the UI?  Just by the browse on the keynoting settings and going to the external server?  I can't see what happens there so I don't know if there is a null external reference that way...